# Bind inserted HTML in PRE tag to a variable

Tags: html, angularjs, bind, pre

I have a DIV HTML element that displays some HTML from a variable:

```
<div contenteditable="true" 
    ng-bind-html="renderHtml(currentOperation.description)" 
    ng-model='currentOperation.description'></div>
```

It renders just fine.

When I type text into the DIV the changes are NOT reflected in the scope variable currentOperation.description

I need a 2 way street here, as is the case with all Angular variables using ng-model

Comment: could you update your question with more clarity?

Comment: Pankaj, what do you mean ? What would you like clarified ?

Comment: will need event listener to do updates.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. As I type into the PRE element, I want currentOperation.description to reflect those changes. I have ng-model='currentOperation.description' so it should take on the changes, however, it does not.

Comment: You seem to be asking about two different things--Angular's scope variables and saving to the back end. Please clarify *in your question*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 2 different things in your case. I would have one to write the content as text, and one to display it. Then either you have the 2 of them like a preview mode, or you use a 3rd variable to know if you are in edit mode or not.

For example:

```
<textarea model="description" ng-show="edit"></textarea>
<div ng-bind-html="description" ng-show="!edit"></div>
```

But the best would be to use a WYSIWYG tool I guess. Most of them allow you to write your own HTML. I use this one https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular

Comment: Cyril, that for the suggestion. I looked into it. It's an overkill for what I need. The problem with edit mode is that text area shows <span> tags and so on. In edit mode, user can only type regular text. Markup is done elsewhere, not under my control. A two way binding is what I truly need here.

Comment: I gave up and used jQuery to get HTML from PRE tag and set it on the variable in save function. Thanks everyone for your time on this.